# deja-dup backups through a virtualbox Ubuntu 12.04 with Windows 7 host?

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, backup, automount

I would like to use a tool like `deja-dup` or similar to have backups of certain directories in a virtualbox Ubuntu 12.04 machine that runs on a Windows 7 host laptop. I am plugging and unplugging this laptop quite often during the day, so ideally this system would be able to auto-mount the USB disk and would not break if I unplug it midway of a backup operation. I have been pointed to `rsync --partial` as a solution, but it seems there isn't a prepackaged solution to the problem so far.

Here is what I found:

BUP to do incremental backups of virtual machines:

- This would allow me to back up the Linux virtual machine itself, but I would still want to at the same time copy some of the contents inside the virtual machine for extra safety.

  https://github.com/apenwarr/bup#readme

Incremental backups to an external disk:

- It doesn't mention partial backups being interrupted midway.

  http://backup2l.sourceforge.net/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to share the USB disk in the Windows OS (if you're Ubuntu VM has access to the hosts network) and perform your backups there. I'm not sure how deja-dup handles being interrupted though.

Comment: Thanks, I have added a question about interrupted updates now: http://askubuntu.com/questions/282343/incremental-backup-tool-that-can-handle-interruptions