# incremental backup tool that can handle interruptions?

Tags: 12.04, backup, tools

Is there a recommended incremental backup tool that can handle interruptions such as the external USB disk being disconnected in the middle of an update?

Answer (score 2):

#### [Rsync](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/rsync) [image: Install rsync] / [Grsync](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/grsync) [image: Install grsync]

The command line file transfer utility Rsync and its GUI Grsync is designed for file transfers via a network connection but can also nicely used for local backup purposes. Due to its provenience from networking it is capable of performing backups with a resume option by using the option `--partial` or `-P`:

> **--partial** By  default, rsync will delete any partially transferred file if        the transfer is interrupted. In some circumstances  it  is  more desirable   to  keep  partially  transferred  files.  Using  the --partial option tells rsync to  keep  the  partial  file  which should  make  a subsequent transfer of the rest of the file much faster <sup>[Manpage rsync](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/rsync.1.html)</sup>

We are also able to define a directory where rsync will store partially transferred files until transfer was complete with the option `--partial-dir=<DIR>`.

An example command for a partial incremental upgrade would be something like:

```
rsync -auxP <source> <destination>
```

> **But:** by all means do not unplug an external USB drive while running a backup as this puts the integrity of your whole filesystem at risk. **Do not trust a backup on  a temporarily unplugged drive!**

Comment: are there any incremental backup systems that integrate rsync partial?

Comment: added grsync GUI for rsync. There also is [luckybackup](http://askubuntu.com/a/4930/3940) based on rsync but I have no idea if they do preserve, they may do so.

Comment: luckybackup doesn't seem to use rsync partial

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is a mix of rsync and sharing the USB device over the network and using rsync to copy the folders. rsync will handle the file level stuff and the network layer means windows will handle the disconnection of the USB drive and in turn shut down the share which means rsync will fail. Or at least as far as I can tell.

Otherwise I think you should start looking at cloud based disk storage as a more complete out of the box solution.

Comment: Windows?  This *is* Ask Ubuntu...